# set_exception_handler() works 2 times with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, exception, mod-rewrite

I have the next simple logging code:

```
function log($exception) {
    error_log($exception->getMessage() . "\n", 3, 'error.log');
}
set_exception_handler('log');
throw new Exception('Holy cow!');
```

And I need to make all requests go to index.php. So my .htaccess file is next:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

And for this situation I have 2 records in log file. But when I remove Rewrite conditions, just 1 record inserts.
How can I avoid of inserting 2 same records? Sorry for my english.

Comment: Could you possibly have a missing image or script embedded in your HTML? That would cause you to end up with extra errors in your log.

Comment: @Ish Kumar, No, it didn't help me. 2 records were inserted into log file too

Comment: @Cfreak, I have a blank index.php file

Comment: @garvey What do you mean a blank index.php?

Comment: @xdazz, I have only 2 files (index.php, .htaccess). Code of this files in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put a favicon.ico in your web root.